# Parsing payload is different with `serverless invoke local` then when deployed with behind APIGateway

Tags: go, aws-lambda, serverless

There seems to be a difference the way serverless handles request payloads with `invoke local` vs the behaviour when deployed to AWS.

The expected behaviour is that you would pull the payload out of the request body like so...

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest)
```

Then unmarshal it into your data type like so...

```
type SearchQuery struct {
    Caller string `json:"caller"`
    Value  string `json:"value"`
}
```

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(request.Body), &searchQuery)
```

However, when invoking the function locally using the `--data` flag the payload is not in the `request.Body`.

```
events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) {
 Resource: (string) "",
 Path: (string) "",
 HTTPMethod: (string) "",
 Headers: (map[string]string) <nil>,
 MultiValueHeaders: (map[string][]string) <nil>,
 QueryStringParameters: (map[string]string) <nil>,
 MultiValueQueryStringParameters: (map[string][]string) <nil>,
 PathParameters: (map[string]string) <nil>,
 StageVariables: (map[string]string) <nil>,
 RequestContext: (events.APIGatewayProxyRequestContext) {
  AccountID: (string) "",
  ResourceID: (string) "",
  Stage: (string) "",
  RequestID: (string) "",
  Identity: (events.APIGatewayRequestIdentity) {
   CognitoIdentityPoolID: (string) "",
   AccountID: (string) "",
   CognitoIdentityID: (string) "",
   Caller: (string) "",
   APIKey: (string) "",
   AccessKey: (string) "",
   SourceIP: (string) "",
   CognitoAuthenticationType: (string) "",
   CognitoAuthenticationProvider: (string) "",
   UserArn: (string) "",
   UserAgent: (string) "",
   User: (string) ""
  },
  ResourcePath: (string) "",
  Authorizer: (map[string]interface {}) <nil>,
  HTTPMethod: (string) "",
  APIID: (string) ""
 },
 Body: (string) "",
 IsBase64Encoded: (bool) false
}
```

It can only be extracted if you use the data type as your request param like so...

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, request SearchQuery) (Response, error)
```

Is there a way to have these two environments working the same?

Comment: Can you post the full `serverless invoke local` command you're using with the `--data` argument value?

Comment: `serverless invoke local -f myfunc --data '{"caller": "foo", "query": "bar@gmail.com"}'`

Comment: The docs are not clear on --data arg and behavior. I assume it doesn't default to requestresponse type?

Answer (score 5):

I got this working by using the `--path` arg instead of `--data` arg and writing out the payload like this.

`serverless invoke local -f myfunc --log --path mydata.json`

```
{
    "body": "{\"caller\": \"foo\", \"value\": \"clark.kent@example.com\"}"
}
```

Comment: when I use this method, the contens of `mydata.json` are received as a json object in the function handler, even though it is a stringfied JSON when deployed to AWS.